# Cannot import Conv1d from Keras

Tags: python, keras

These are my imports

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
```

and it's showing me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 13
     11 from keras.layers import Dense
     12 from keras.layers import Flatten
---> 13 from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
     14 from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
     15 from matplotlib import pyplot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.convolutional'
```

i have tried evrything from updating every library to latest python version but still its showing this problem even i have created a new python environment for it but still the same problem . I am running this in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: On a Jupyter Notebook cell, can you run `!pip install --upgrade keras` to see if it updates in the notebook itself?

Comment: You are using very old or plain wrong imports, just fix them by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick Fix

```
# Original Line
# from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D

# Update
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D
```

## Explanation

`keras` is installed properly as if it was not, an error would be observed at the first line where a module is imported from keras and not at line 13.

Now, this tells us that `keras` is good to go but there is some problem with `from keras.layers.convolutional`. If you want to import `Conv1D` or any layer just use -

```
from keras.layers.layer_name
```

where layer_name is the name of your layer.

You can refer [this](https://keras.io/api/layers/) for more information about keras layers.